# Summation of fractional numbers with ∑()

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I have been working on a lengthy math expression and finally I simplified it as $\sum_{t=0}^T C_t^{T}(-1)^t\Gamma(1+t/\beta_A)$ where 
$C_t^{T}$ is $T!/(T-t)!t!$

The problem is, I have to validate this expression by using fractional experimental results, i.e $T$ must be fractional. However, none of the math programs count the above expression correctly when $T$ is not integer.

What can I do? Thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: Use a Computer algebra system? Maple, Mathematica...

Comment: I am using both but they do not count fractional numbers :)

Comment: Your expression doesn't make much sense, there is no dependency of the factors on $t$.

Comment: $\binom{x}{k}$ is fine when $x$ is fractional.  It is just $x(x-1) \cdots (x-k+1) / k!$.  When $k$ is fractional it gets a little tricky and you have to use the gamma function.

Comment: There was a typo, I fixed it

Comment: You seem to have some misconception about what the $\sum_{a}^{b}$ means, please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation. Having non-integer $b$ does not really make much sense, unless you clearly define what you mean by that.

Comment: @JairTaylor: this doesn't help. The problem is with the fractional summation.

Answer (score 1):

Your model is inherently time-discrete by design, so thinking of fractional times seems a nonsense.

Maybe you can switch to a continuous time description, where the summation would turn to an integration, but with the little information given, I can't say more.

Comment: I know Gamma function will fix the problem in binomial but the main problem is $T$. Let's say $T=7.5$, $t$ does the summation up to $7$ but it did not add $7.5$. That's the main problem

Comment: @Eylem: as you don't seem to understand my answer, I can't help you further.

Comment: How can I change the summation to an integration? I am sorry I post my answer to a wrong place.